# Boolean Algebra Axioms in Joy of Sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In Keith Devlin's book Joy of Sets, he has outlined a problem (1.8.1) on Boolean Algebra. Besides the axioms for commutativity, associativity and distributivity, he presents the following axioms (I am showing the relevant ones for the question)

(B3) $(b \land c) \lor c = c$ and $(b \lor c) \land c = c$

(B5) $(b \land -b) \lor b = b$ and $(b \lor -b) \land b = b$

He then asks the student to prove that all $(b \land -b)$ are equal and denoted by 0.

My question is this : I feel B5 is wrongly stated as it can be derived immediately from B3 (substituting -b for b, and b for c). I think the correct statement would be :

(B5) $(b \land -b) \lor a = a$ and $(b \lor -b) \land a = a$

I would like to know if I am correct, or if I am wrong what is wrong with my reasoning.

Comment: Your reasoning sounds compelling.

Comment: How do you derive B5 from B3? If you just substitute $b$ for $c$ you get $(b\land b)\lor b=b$, not $(b\land -b)\lor b=b$.

Comment: @Wojowu - i have corrected the answer - i meant to say that B3 implies B5.

Comment: Ah, okay, I see now.